# Equation of a line.. or WHAT?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm SO lost. I would love to understand this, any easy help to make me understand it better would be highly appreciated.

$f(x_1) = \theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1$

$f(x_1) = \theta_0 + \theta_1  x_1 + \theta_2 x_1^2$

What exactly makes the line in the first equation a curve in the second? Is it the new parameter $\theta$ that was added? Or was it the new $x$ feature?

$f(x_1) = \theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1$ is clearly the graph of a line... 
but what if we had:
$f(x_1, x_2, x_3 ... x_n) = \theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1 + \cdots + \theta_n x_n$

Is this graph a line in multiple dimensions? is it a curve? Does it have the shape of a polynomial of degree $3$? How would I know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the $\theta_i$ are constants, it's the nonlinear term $x_1^2$ that makes the second equation a nonlinear curve.

A line is a function that depends linearly on one parameter.

In $n$ dimensions, a line will look like this

$$f(t) = \mathbf{x}_0 + t (\theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots, \theta_n)$$

where $\mathbf{x}_0$ is a fixed $n$ dimensional point.

Something of the form

$$f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1 + \theta_2 x_2 + \cdots + \theta_n x_n$$

is an $n$ dimensional *plane*, not a line.

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for answering. Assume that  $x_2 = x_1^2$ then $f(x_1 , x_2) = theta_o + theta_1 x_1 + theta_2 x_2 $ would still be a line?

Comment: I don't think this is right. Your first example is a function of two variables. Its graph is a plane in space. The second example is a curved surface in space.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, you are right. Let me edit.

Comment: @IdkHowToRc No, that would be the same as your second example. Please note my update.

Comment: @AlexisOlson but if$ x_2 = x_1^2 then f(x_1, x_2) = theta_o + theta_1 x_1 + theta_2 x_2$ would end up being a curve not a plane